# How to open FGDB raster in ENVI?

Tags: envi

I have File GeoDatabase raster image that is combined with multi-bands and I want to do classification (ISO unsupervised) in ENVI.

How can I open a FGDB raster in ENVI?

Answer (score 1):

From the [ENVI Help](http://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/OpeningRemoteDatasets.html):

> **Connect to a File or Personal Geodatabase**
>
> Run ENVI in **32-bit mode** from the Windows Start menu before performing these steps.
>
> To create a new connection to a file or personal geodatabase:
>
> 1. From the Remote Connection Manager dialog menu bar, select one of the following:
>
>    - Connection > Add File Geodatabase. The Add File
>        Geodatabase dialog appears.
>    - Connection > Add Personal Geodatabase.
>        The Add Personal Geodatabase dialog appears.
> 2. Enter a Catalog Path, or click the Browse button to browse to look for a geodatabase. An example of the catalog path format is provided
>      in the dialog.
> 3. Click OK. The list of available folders and datasets appear in the left panel of the Remote Connection Manager dialog.
> 4. Navigate to a dataset and select it. The properties for the selected dataset appear in the right panel of the dialog. You cannot edit the
>      properties for a file or personal geodatabase. See Geodatabases for
>      additional details.
> 5. Click Open Dataset to open the dataset in ENVI. Depending on your display preferences, the dataset may automatically display in the
>      Image window and appear in the Layer Manager. If it does not
>      automatically display, you can drag-and-drop remote dataset layers
>      from the Layer Manager to the Image window or to multiple views.